# add a label "0" to the origine, change the mark and shift the label

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to have

- a label "0" at the origin,
- with a **circle mark** replacing the tik mark (vertical dash)
- and shifted to the right

so as not to interfere with the "y" line.

I tried several things but it didn't work out. :/ Any idea how to do so?

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}% permet de déterminer une taille de fenêtre
%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans 
%                       \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,calc,math,shapes,arrows.meta,backgrounds}
%%%%
\tikzset{%
    graphpgf/.style={%
        font={\sansmath\sffamily\Large}, 
        line cap=round, line join=round, 
        >={Latex[length=3mm]}, 
        x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, 
        background rectangle/.style={fill=white, shift={(0pt, 0pt)}},
        show background rectangle,
        inner frame sep=15pt
    }
}

%%%     Paramètre graphique des graphiques orthonormés pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/graphxy/.style={
        %%%%%%%%%%  Dimensionnement de l'image  %%%%%%%%%%
        width=12cm,
        height=12cm,
        unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
        %%%%%%%%%%  esthétique des axes  %%%%%%%%%%
        xlabel=$\mathrm{x}$,         ylabel=$\mathrm{y}$,
        axis lines = middle,
        enlargelimits=false,
        line width=0.4mm,
        every major grid/.append style={black!20, line width=0.35mm,},
        every minor grid/.append style={black!15, line width=0.15mm,},
        every major tick/.append style={line width=0.4 mm, major tick length=7pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={line width=0.15mm, minor tick length=4pt, black},
        %axis background/.style={fill=white},
        grid=both,
        axis line style = {shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt, -{Latex[length=3mm]}},
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},yshift=-3.5pt, anchor=north west, font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large},
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},xshift=-3.5pt,, anchor=south east, font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large},
        title style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large, align=center, inner sep=12pt,},
        }
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[graphpgf]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Data Table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{axis}[%
    graphxy,
    %%%     Axe x
    xlabel=$\mathrm{n}$,
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick style={%
        mark=*,
        %anchor=south east,
        %ticklabel pos=below right
        },
    xmin=-0-.5, xmax=11+.5,
    xtick={-15,...,15},
    %minor xtick={-10,...,8},
    domain=-3:3,
    %%%     Axe x
    ylabel=$\mathrm{u_n}$,
    ymin=-0.3-.5,ymax=7+.5,
    ytick={-15,...,15},
    %minor ytick={-8,...,8},
    %minor tick num=1,
    restrict y to domain=-6:6,
           ]%
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Final result

[image]

Code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans 
%                       \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    matrix,
    arrows,
    arrows.meta,
    calc,
    math,
    shapes,
    backgrounds,
    decorations.markings,
    }
%%%%
\tikzset{%
    graphpgf/.style={%
        font={\sansmath\sffamily\Large}, 
        line cap=round, line join=round, 
        >={Latex[length=3mm]}, 
        x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, 
        background rectangle/.style={fill=white, shift={(0pt, 0pt)}},
        show background rectangle,
        inner frame sep=15pt
    }
}

%%%     Paramètre graphique des graphiques orthonormés pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{%
    /pgfplots/graphxy/.style={%
        %%%%%%%%%%  Dimensionnement de l'image  %%%%%%%%%%
        width=12.5cm,
        height=12.5cm,
        unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
        %%%%%%%%%%  esthétique des axes  %%%%%%%%%%
        xlabel=$\mathrm{x}$,         ylabel=$\mathrm{y}$,
        axis lines = middle,
        enlargelimits=false,
        line width=0.4mm,
        every major grid/.append style={black!20, line width=0.35mm,},
        every minor grid/.append style={black!15, line width=0.15mm,},
        every major tick/.append style={line width=0.4 mm, major tick length=7pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={line width=0.15mm, minor tick length=4pt, black},
        %axis background/.style={fill=white},
        grid=both,
        axis line style = {shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt, -{Latex[length=3mm]}},
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},yshift=-3.5pt, anchor=north west, font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large},
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},xshift=-3.5pt,, anchor=south east, font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large},
        title style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large, align=center, inner sep=12pt,},
        extra x ticks={0},
        extra x tick style={%
            grid= none,
            xticklabel style={%
                below right,
            },
            every major tick/.append style={
                scale=1,
                draw=none,
                postaction={decorate},
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=between positions 3.5pt and 1 step 7pt with{
                      \draw[fill] (0, 0) circle (2pt);
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[graphpgf]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Data Table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{axis}[%
    graphxy,
    %%%     Axe x
    xlabel=$\mathrm{n}$,
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick style={%
        xticklabel style={below right},
        every major grid/.append style={black,},
        every major tick/.append style={black},
        },
    xmin=-0-.5, xmax=11+.5,
    xtick={-15,...,15},
    %minor xtick={-10,...,8},
    domain=-3:3,
    %%%     Axe x
    ylabel=$\mathrm{u_n}$,
    ymin=-0-.5,ymax=7+.5,
    ytick={-15,...,15},
    %minor ytick={-8,...,8},
    %minor tick num=1,
    restrict y to domain=-6:6,
           ]%
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: extra x tick style={
        xticklabel style={below right},
        },

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP solved it himself as stated in the comment.

Comment: I would have closed it if i found the solution, but I'm still looking how to do a circle mark properly. I tried "mark=*", etc. But it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ticklabel` to specify what you want to use as label text of extra tick 0.

Here I use upper case `O` as an example:

```
    extra x tick style={
      xticklabel style={below left}, 
      xticklabel={O}
    },
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}% permet de déterminer une taille de fenêtre
%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans 
%                       \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,calc,math,shapes,arrows.meta,backgrounds}
%%%%
\tikzset{%
    graphpgf/.style={%
        font={\sansmath\sffamily\Large}, 
        line cap=round, line join=round, 
        >={Latex[length=3mm]}, 
        x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, 
        background rectangle/.style={fill=white, shift={(0pt, 0pt)}},
        show background rectangle,
        inner frame sep=15pt
    }
}

%%%     Paramètre graphique des graphiques orthonormés pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/graphxy/.style={
        %%%%%%%%%%  Dimensionnement de l'image  %%%%%%%%%%
        width=12cm,
        height=12cm,
        unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
        %%%%%%%%%%  esthétique des axes  %%%%%%%%%%
        xlabel=$\mathrm{x}$,         ylabel=$\mathrm{y}$,
        axis lines = middle,
        enlargelimits=false,
        line width=0.4mm,
        every major grid/.append style={black!20, line width=0.35mm,},
        every minor grid/.append style={black!15, line width=0.15mm,},
        every major tick/.append style={line width=0.4 mm, major tick length=7pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={line width=0.15mm, minor tick length=4pt, black},
        %axis background/.style={fill=white},
        grid=both,
        axis line style = {shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt, -{Latex[length=3mm]}},
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},yshift=-3.5pt, anchor=north west, font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large},
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},xshift=-3.5pt,, anchor=south east, font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large},
        title style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large, align=center, inner sep=12pt,},
        }
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[graphpgf]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Data Table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{axis}[%
    graphxy,
    %%%     Axe x
    xlabel=$\mathrm{n}$,
    extra x ticks={0},
    extra x tick style={
      xticklabel style={below right}, 
      xticklabel={O}
    },
    xmin=-0-.5, xmax=11+.5,
    xtick={-15,...,15},
    %minor xtick={-10,...,8},
    domain=-3:3,
    %%%     Axe x
    ylabel=$\mathrm{u_n}$,
    ymin=-0.3-.5,ymax=7+.5,
    ytick={-15,...,15},
    %minor ytick={-8,...,8},
    %minor tick num=1,
    restrict y to domain=-6:6,
           ]%
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update

To replace the tick line by a filled circle, a path decoration is used.

```
% in preamble
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

% new option added to "axis" environment
    tick style={
      draw=none,
      red, thick, % for highlighting
      postaction={decorate},
      decoration={
        markings,
        % 7pt is from "major tick length=7pt", and 3.5pt is half of 7pt
        mark=between positions 3.5pt and 1 step 7pt with {
          \draw[fill] (0, 0) circle (2pt);
        }
      }
    },
```

Full example

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}% permet de déterminer une taille de fenêtre
%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans 
%                       \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,calc,math,shapes,arrows.meta,backgrounds}
%%%%
\tikzset{%
    graphpgf/.style={%
        font={\sansmath\sffamily\Large}, 
        line cap=round, line join=round, 
        >={Latex[length=3mm]}, 
        x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, 
        background rectangle/.style={fill=white, shift={(0pt, 0pt)}},
        show background rectangle,
        inner frame sep=15pt
    }
}

%%%     Paramètre graphique des graphiques orthonormés pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/graphxy/.style={
        %%%%%%%%%%  Dimensionnement de l'image  %%%%%%%%%%
        width=12cm,
        height=12cm,
        unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
        %%%%%%%%%%  esthétique des axes  %%%%%%%%%%
        xlabel=$\mathrm{x}$,         ylabel=$\mathrm{y}$,
        axis lines = middle,
        enlargelimits=false,
        line width=0.4mm,
        every major grid/.append style={black!20, line width=0.35mm,},
        every minor grid/.append style={black!15, line width=0.15mm,},
        every major tick/.append style={line width=0.4 mm, major tick length=7pt, black},
        every minor tick/.append style={line width=0.15mm, minor tick length=4pt, black},
        %axis background/.style={fill=white},
        grid=both,
        axis line style = {shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt, -{Latex[length=3mm]}},
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},yshift=-3.5pt, anchor=north west, font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large},
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},xshift=-3.5pt,, anchor=south east, font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large},
        title style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily\Large, align=center, inner sep=12pt,},
        }
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[graphpgf]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Data Table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{axis}[%
    graphxy,
    %%%     Axe x
    xlabel=$\mathrm{n}$,
    extra x ticks={0},
%    extra x tick style={
%      xticklabel style={below right}, 
%      xticklabel={O}
%    },
    xmin=-0-.5, xmax=11+.5,
    xtick={-15,...,15},
    %minor xtick={-10,...,8},
    domain=-3:3,
    %%%     Axe x
    ylabel=$\mathrm{u_n}$,
    ymin=-0.3-.5,ymax=7+.5,
    ytick={-15,...,15},
    %minor ytick={-8,...,8},
    %minor tick num=1,
    restrict y to domain=-6:6,
    tick style={
      draw=none,
      red, thick, % for highlighting
      postaction={decorate},
      decoration={
        markings,
        % 7pt is from "major tick length=7pt", and 3.5pt is half of 7pt
        mark=between positions 3.5pt and 1 step 7pt with {
          \draw[fill] (0, 0) circle (2pt);
        }
      }
    },
]%
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the ticks on y-axis are covered by the grid line of extra x tick at x=0. I will have a look if this can be easily fixed.

Comment: any idea how to change the tick mark to have a circle and not a dash?

Comment: @Nilcouv You want to change the short dashes now nearby "1", "2", ..., "11" to be small circles? I (and others on this site) might misunderstand your requirement before. You can add an image illustrating what you want and then vote to reopen the question.

Comment: yes, it is what I mean

Comment: @Nilcouv See my updated answer.

Comment: I used your code to fixe what were left. I edited my post to add my final code for people who could look for the same problem.

Comment: @Nilcouv That's the best. Thank you.